# How to access Friend list of facebook account

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to access friend list from facebook account,
the proble is that the friend list is accessed in simulatore but not in device, so what i have to do about this??

Thanks...

```
  FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
friendsRequest.session = FBSession.activeSession;

[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %lu friends", (unsigned long)friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends)
    {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ ", friend.name);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) FBRequestConnection *connection;

-(void)requestAllFreindsWithHandler:(FBRequestHandler)handler;
    {
        NSAssert([FBSession activeSession] != nil, @"Login required ");
        self.connection = [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:handler];

    }
```